# How to programmatically create an entity and fill in entity reference fields

Tags: 7, entities

I'm trying to create an entity that has a number of entity refernce fields, and I'm confused about the best way to do that. so far I've gotten as far as this

```
$entity = entity_create('mytype', $values);
$entity->field_ref = array('und' => array(0 => array('value' => "2")));
```

Creating the entity works fine, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to fill in the entity references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column name for a field isn't always `value`; in the case of entity references it's `target_id` if I remember rightly.

Try this:

```
$entity = entity_create('mytype', $values);
$entity->field_ref = array('und' => array(0 => array('target_id' => "2")));
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help someone:

```
$entity_ids = array(15,78,45,78);
$count = 0;
foreach ($entity_ids as $id) {
  $count++;
  $node->field_entity_ref[$node->language][$count]['target_id'] = $id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using contrib [Entity module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity), you can use [entity metadata wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers) syntax, for example:

```
$entity = entity_create('mytype', array('type' => 'my_bundle'));
try {
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('mytype', $entity);
  $wrapper->field_ref = '123';
  $wrapper->field_multi_ref = array('123', '456');
  $wrapper->save();
}
catch (EntityMetadataWrapperException $e) {
  watchdog_exception('my_module', $e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need add new reference to existing entity references .

```
$counter = 0;
$node_reference = array();
while (!is_null($entity->field_ref['und'][$counter]))
{
    $node_reference[$counter]= $entity->field_ref['und'][$counter];
    $counter++;
}
$node_reference[$counter]= array('target_id' => $release_nid);
$entity->field_ref= array('und' => $node_reference);
```